# restrict multiple selection of radio button in HTML?

Tags: html

The below HTML code i have allows multiple selection of radio button ? How do i limit it so that only one can be chooses at a time from the list

```
         <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend></legend>
            <label for="Arrived/Left">Arrived/Left Destination</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Arrived/Left" id="Arrived/Left" value="Arrived/Left">
            <label for="Delayed">Delayed</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Delayed" id="Delayed" value="Delayed">    
            <label for="Canceled">Canceled</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Canceled" id="Canceled" value="Canceled">
            <label for="getupdate">Post to Get Update ?</label>
            <input type="radio" name="getupdate" id="getupdate" value="getupdate">
            <label for="Other">Other</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Other" id="Other" value="Other">
          </fieldset>
```

Comment: is  this a jquery code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First this is not jQuery.. this is HTML..

Second you can do that by giving all the radio buttons of the same group (where you want only one to be selected) the same name..

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend></legend>
        <label for="Arrived/Left">Arrived/Left Destination</label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" id="Arrived/Left" value="Arrived/Left">
        <label for="Delayed">Delayed</label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" id="Delayed" value="Delayed">    
        <label for="Canceled">Canceled</label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" id="Canceled" value="Canceled">
        <label for="getupdate">Post to Get Update ?</label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" id="getupdate" value="getupdate">
        <label for="Other">Other</label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" id="Other" value="Other">
      </fieldset>
```

Comment: ... which is how you're *supposed* to do it.

Comment: What is meant is that the developer may have several radio button groups.. practically multiple radio buttons will be selected.. but one for each group.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

use name attribute to group your radio button

```
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend></legend>
        <label for="Arrived/Left">Arrived/Left Destination</label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" id="Arrived/Left" value="Arrived/Left">
        <label for="Delayed">Delayed</label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" id="Delayed" value="Delayed">    
        <label for="Canceled">Canceled</label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" id="Canceled" value="Canceled">
        <label for="getupdate">Post to Get Update ?</label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" id="getupdate" value="getupdate">
        <label for="Other">Other</label>
        <input type="radio" name="status" id="Other" value="Other">
      </fieldset>
```

> You define radio button groups with the name property (radio buttons with the same name belong to the same group).

Answer (score 1):

You are having a different name for each of your radio. Change the names of all the input radio to a single name. The radios having the same name will behave as a single group which is what your requirement.

*You haven't closed the input tags.

Hope this helps.